# Google Analytics: Event Tracking Parameters

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am using ga for my website.

but when i call track event like this

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'abc', 'def','pqr','xyz']);
```

it does not work but when i call function by removing last parameter i.e 'xyz' it works properly it looks like this

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'abc', 'def','pqr']);
```

where _gaq is an array which contains my ga account no. and domain info.

my concern is I want to pass four parameter with '_trackEvent' parameter like this..

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action,label,value]);
```

but this is not working.

Plz help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Google Analytics API Event Tracking Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) states that the `trackEvent` method accepts 5 parameters:

- category (required)
- action (required)
- label (optional)
- value (optional)
- non-interactive boolean (optional)

The second-to-last parameter (value) [has to be an integer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#Values), and so does not work when a string is passed.